# filter by observation that cumulate X% of values

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to filter by observations (after sorting in decreasing way in every group) that cumulate X % of values, in my case less than or equal to 80 percent of total of the values. And that in every group.

So from this dataframe below:

```
Group<-c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C")

value<-c(c(2,3,6,3,1,1,3,3,5,4,3,5,3,4,2))
data1<-data.frame(Group,value)
data1<-data1%>%arrange(Group,desc(value))%>%
  group_by(Group)%>%mutate(pct=round (100*value/sum(value),1))%>%
  mutate(cumPct=cumsum(pct))
```

I would like to have the below filtered dataframe according to conditions I decribed above:

```
  Group value  pct cumPct
1     A     6 40.0   40.0
2     A     3 20.0   60.0
3     A     3 20.0   80.0
4     B     5 41.7   41.7
5     B     3 25.0   66.7
6     C     5 23.8   23.8
7     C     4 19.0   42.8
8     C     4 19.0   61.8
9     C     3 14.3   76.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can arrange the data in descending order of `value`, for each `Group` calculate `pct` and  `cum_pct` and select rows where `cum_pct` is less than equal to 80.

```
library(dplyr)

data1 %>%
  arrange(Group, desc(value)) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(pct = value/sum(value) * 100, 
         cum_pct = cumsum(pct)) %>%
  filter(cum_pct <= 80)

#  Group value   pct cum_pct
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 A         6  40      40  
#2 A         3  20      60  
#3 A         3  20      80  
#4 B         5  41.7    41.7
#5 B         3  25      66.7
#6 C         5  23.8    23.8
#7 C         4  19.0    42.9
#8 C         4  19.0    61.9
#9 C         3  14.3    76.2
```